# Join PIVOT table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

How can I group pivot query by the category. I can achieve this in Excel but I wanted to do in SQL Oracle query.

Let say we have data like this:-

[image]

I can simply pivot to **get grade count by subject** and **get grade count by category** as below

```
select * from (select studentID, subject, grade from table_student)
PIVOT 
(
sum (grade) FOR (subject) IN ('A','B','C')
)
order by studentID;
```

---

```
select * from (select studentID, category, grade from table_student)
PIVOT 
(
sum (grade) FOR (category) IN ('Common','Science')
)
order by studentID;
```

But my question can I combine these query and get result like below using SQL?

[image: combine category and subject]

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivot on both `Subject` and `Category`:

```sql
SELECT p.*,
       LEAST(common_math, common_history, science_chemistry, science_biology) AS highest_grade
FROM   table_name
PIVOT (
  MAX(grade) FOR (subject, category) IN (
    ('Math',      'Common') AS common_math,
    ('History',   'Common') AS common_history,
    ('Chemistry', 'Science') AS science_chemistry,
    ('Biology',   'Science') AS science_biology
  )
) p
```

*(Note: In your sample data, the grades are alphabetic, rather than numeric, so your expected `grand_total` output does not make sense and I've shown highest grade instead. If you had numeric values then, in the `SELECT` clause, you can add the values for each subject/category.)*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (student_id, subject, category, grade) AS
SELECT 1, 'Math',      'Common',  'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Chemistry', 'Science', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Biology',   'Science', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'History',   'Common',  'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Math',      'Common',  'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Chemistry', 'Science', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Biology',   'Science', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'History',   'Common',  'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Math',      'Common',  'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Chemistry', 'Science', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Biology',   'Science', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'History',   'Common',  'C' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| STUDENT_ID | COMMON_MATH | COMMON_HISTORY | SCIENCE_CHEMISTRY | SCIENCE_BIOLOGY | HIGHEST_GRADE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A | C | B | A |
| 2 | B | B | A | B | A |
| 3 | A | C | C | A | A |

---

If you want the grand total then you can use `ROLLUP` and conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(TO_CHAR(student_id), 'Grand Total') AS student_id,
       MIN(CASE WHEN category = 'Common'  AND Subject = 'Math'      THEN Grade END) AS common_math,
       MIN(CASE WHEN category = 'Common'  AND Subject = 'History'   THEN Grade END) AS common_history,
       MIN(CASE WHEN category = 'Science' AND Subject = 'Chemistry' THEN Grade END) AS science_chemistry,
       MIN(CASE WHEN category = 'Science' AND Subject = 'Biology'   THEN Grade END) AS science_biology,
       MIN(Grade) AS highest_grade
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY ROLLUP(student_id);
```

Which outputs:

| STUDENT_ID | COMMON_MATH | COMMON_HISTORY | SCIENCE_CHEMISTRY | SCIENCE_BIOLOGY | HIGHEST_GRADE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A | C | B | A |
| 2 | B | B | A | B | A |
| 3 | A | C | C | A | A |
| Grand Total | A | A | A | A | A |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1f90ZFLe)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the report like requested but there is a lot of compromises involved. First of all is the fact that you can't have different datatypes in the same column so you should convert all numbers to varchar datatype. And then there is a question of the purpose  of such a report. Anyway it could be done using [MODEL](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm) clause:

Sample data:

```sql
WITH
    tbl (STUDENT_ID, SUBJECT, CATEGORY, GRADE) AS
        ( Select 1,     'Math',         'Common',   'A' From Dual Union All
            Select 3,   'Chemistry',    'Science',  'C' From Dual Union All
            Select 1,   'Chemistry',    'Science',  'A' From Dual Union All
            Select 2,   'Math',         'Common',   'B' From Dual Union All
            Select 1,   'Biology',      'Science',  'B' From Dual Union All
            Select 1,   'History',      'Common',   'A' From Dual Union All
            Select 3,   'Biology',      'Science',  'A' From Dual Union All
            Select 2,   'Biology',      'Science',  'B' From Dual Union All
            Select 3,   'History',      'Common',   'C' From Dual Union All
            Select 2,   'Chemistry',    'Science',  'A' From Dual Union All
            Select 3,   'Math',         'Common',   'A' From Dual Union All
            Select 2,   'History',      'Common',   'B' From Dual 
        )
```

SQL

```sql
SELECT  STUDENT_ID, 
        CASE WHEN IDX = 999 THEN Min(HIST) ELSE Max(HIST) END "HIST", 
        CASE WHEN IDX = 999 THEN Min(MATH) ELSE Max(MATH) END "MATH", 
        CASE WHEN IDX = 999 THEN Min(BIO) ELSE Max(BIO) END "BIO", 
        CASE WHEN IDX = 999 THEN Min(CHEM) ELSE Max(CHEM) END "CHEM",
        CASE  WHEN IDX Between 1 And 999 THEN  To_Char(Sum(CASE WHEN IDX Between 1 And 999 
              THEN To_Number(TOTAL) ELSE 0 END))  
        ELSE Max(TOTAL) 
        END "TOTAL"
FROM
    ( SELECT  IDX, STUDENT_ID, HIST, MATH, BIO, CHEM, TOTAL
      FROM( Select     IDX,  
                    CASE  WHEN IDX = 999 THEN 'Grand Total '
                          WHEN IDX = 0 THEN 'Student ID '
                          WHEN IDX = -1 THEN 'Per Category And Subject '
                          WHEN IDX = -2 THEN 'COUNT OF GRADES REPORT' 
                    ELSE To_Char(STUDENT_ID) END "STUDENT_ID", 
                    --
                    CASE  WHEN IDX = 0 THEN 'History'
                          WHEN IDX = -1 And CAT = 'Common' THEN CAT 
                          WHEN IDX = -2  THEN ''
                    ELSE HIST END "HIST", 
                    --
                    CASE  WHEN IDX = 0 THEN 'Math' 
                          WHEN IDX = -1 THEN ''
                          WHEN IDX = -2 THEN ''
                    ELSE MATH END "MATH", 
                    --
                    CASE  WHEN IDX = 0 THEN 'Biology'
                          WHEN IDX = -1 And CAT = 'Science' THEN CAT 
                          WHEN IDX = -2 THEN ''
                    ELSE BIO END "BIO", 
                    --
                    CASE  WHEN IDX = 0 THEN 'Chemistry' 
                          WHEN IDX = -1 THEN ''
                          WHEN IDX = -2 THEN ''
                    ELSE CHEM END "CHEM",
                    CASE  WHEN IDX = 0 THEN 'Total' 
                          WHEN IDX = -1 THEN 'Grand'
                          WHEN IDX = -2 THEN ''
                    ELSE To_Char(TOTAL) END "TOTAL",
                    TOTAL "GRAND_TOTAL"
          From    (   Select    0 "IDX", STUDENT_ID, SUBJECT, CATEGORY, GRADE
                      From      tbl   
                  ) 
            MODEL   Partition By (  SUBJECT, CATEGORY )
                    Dimension By (  STUDENT_ID  )
                    Measures  ( IDX, GRADE, CAST('xxx' as VarChar2(20)) as CAT, 0 as TOTAL,
                              CAST('Math' as VarChar(20)) as MATH, CAST('Chemistry' as VarChar(20)) as CHEM,
                              CAST('Biology' as VarChar(20)) as BIO, CAST('History' as VarChar(20)) as HIST  )
            RULES  ITERATE(10)
                  ( IDX[-2] = -2,
                    IDX[-1] = -1,
                    CAT[-1] = CV(CATEGORY),
                    IDX[0] = 0,
                    CAT[0] = 'Subject',
                    --
                    IDX[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] = ITERATION_NUMBER + 1,
                    HIST[ANY] = CASE WHEN CV(SUBJECT) = 'History' And GRADE[CV()] Is Not Null THEN 1 END,
                    MATH[ANY] = CASE WHEN CV(SUBJECT) = 'Math' And GRADE[CV()] Is Not Null THEN 1 END,
                    BIO[ANY] = CASE WHEN CV(SUBJECT) = 'Biology' And GRADE[CV()] Is Not Null THEN 1 END,
                    CHEM[ANY] = CASE WHEN CV(SUBJECT) = 'Chemistry' And GRADE[CV()] Is Not Null THEN 1 END,
                    TOTAL[ANY] =  Count(CASE WHEN GRADE Is Not Null THEN GRADE END)[STUDENT_ID = CV() And CV(SUBJECT) = 'History'] + 
                                  Count(CASE WHEN GRADE Is Not Null THEN GRADE END)[STUDENT_ID = CV() And CV(SUBJECT) = 'Math'] + 
                                  Count(CASE WHEN GRADE Is Not Null THEN GRADE END)[STUDENT_ID = CV() And CV(SUBJECT) = 'Biology'] + 
                                  Count(CASE WHEN GRADE Is Not Null THEN GRADE END)[STUDENT_ID = CV() And CV(SUBJECT) = 'Chemistry'],
                    --
                    IDX[999] = 999,
                    HIST[999] = Count(CASE WHEN GRADE Is Not Null THEN GRADE END)[STUDENT_ID Is Not Null],
                    MATH[999] = Count(CASE WHEN GRADE Is Not Null THEN GRADE END)[STUDENT_ID Is Not Null],
                    BIO[999] = Count(CASE WHEN GRADE Is Not Null THEN GRADE END)[STUDENT_ID Is Not Null],
                    CHEM[999] = Count(CASE WHEN GRADE Is Not Null THEN GRADE END)[STUDENT_ID Is Not Null],
                    TOTAL[999] =  Count(CASE WHEN GRADE Is Not Null THEN GRADE END)[STUDENT_ID Is Not Null] 
                  )
        
        )
      WHERE IDX <=  ( Select Count(DISTINCT STUDENT_ID) From tbl  ) OR IDX = 999
    )
GROUP BY STUDENT_ID, IDX
ORDER BY CASE WHEN SubStr(STUDENT_ID, 1, 1) In('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9', 'G') Then 'xx' || STUDENT_ID
              WHEN SubStr(STUDENT_ID, 1, 1) = 'A' THEN 'xA'
         ELSE STUDENT_ID END
```

As you can see there is a lot of code but MODEL gives you options to treat your data prety much like with excel sheet. It is not suitable for many queries but from time to time could be very handy.
R e s u l t :

| STUDENT_ID | HIST | MATH | BIO | CHEM | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COUNT OF GRADES REPORT |  |  |  |  |  |
| Per Category And Subject | Common |  | Science |  | Grand |
| Student ID | History | Math | Biology | Chemistry | Total |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| Grand Total | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 12 |